# How to Implement Dependency Injection for Generic Nhibernate Reporsitory for use of asp.net / MVC3 applications?

Tags: nhibernate, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, repository-pattern

In continuation to earlier SO question : [Remote Database response very slow of asp.net application using NHIbernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534728/remote-database-response-very-slow-of-asp-net-application-using-nhibernate/11535843)

In the solution of above problem, it is suggested to implement DI.
Can anyone provide the way to implement DI eg. Ninject, Windsor or any other ?

Please take a CommonRepository mentioned in prior post.

If this question looks like a stupidity, please excuse me to ask this one.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good books on nhibernate that would be worthwhile looking into. Also there are lot of blog posts and open source projects around that will help you out.

Some resources that I found useful are

- [Nhibernate Cookbook 3.0](http://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book)
- [FunnelWeb Blog Engine](http://www.funnelweblog.com)
- [Create an ASP.NET MVC application with Windsor and NHibernate at the speed of nuget](http://joseoncode.com/2011/03/07/create-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-windsor-and-nhibernate-at-the-speed-of-nuget/)
- [S#arpe Lite](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/11/11/s-arp-lite-the-basics.aspx)